# What is the right way to deal with reference to old project with old entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependencies

We are busy migrating our solution to MVC, with all the latest and greatest goodies, however there is a lot of twisted logic in a massive pile of spaghetti that I'm afraid to touch. The affected project is being rewritten piece by piece, but in the mean time it needs to be included in the new solution..

```
OldSpaghettiMonster
+ Depends on EntityFramework 4.0.0

FancyMvcSite
+ Depends on OldSpaghettiMonster
+ Depends on EntityFramework 6.x
+ Lots of other neat and tidy business layer stuff
```

When I add a reference to OldSpaghettiMonster in the new FancyMvcSite I get a warning that I need to add a reference to EF 4.0.0 as well.. what is the "right way" to deal with this situation?

Comment: Are you sure EF4-based code will be compatible with EF6 or 7? :\

Comment: Well, the code has a semi-reasonable interface, so it just returns some objects to the mvc project